# angular6 matRipple not working when added dynamically

Tags: html, css, angular-material, angular6, ripple

I want to add a Ripple effect only if the user can select that element. For that I am sending the `canSelect` property from the parent component to the child component now if `canSelect` is true, then only the Ripple effect should be added.

This is what I have tried so far:

**Component**

```
@Input() canSelect?: boolean = false;
```

**Html template**

```
<div [attr.matRipple]="canSelect ? '' : null"> select </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  [`[matRippleDisabled]`](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/examples) in case your `canSelect` is `true/false`

AS:

`<div matRipple [matRippleDisabled]="canSelect"> select </div>`